# How to chage the postion of tooltip in kendo chart

Tags: kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-dataviz

Hi i have kendo chart in my application,and it is displaying tool-tip in right side I want to change the position of tool-tip to left side.How to do this one.
 My chart code is

```
         $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Internet Users"
           },
         legend: {
    position: "bottom"
},
seriesDefaults: {
    type: "column"
},
series: [{
    name: "World",
    data: [15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6]},
{
    name: "United States",
    data: [67.96, 68.93, 75, 74, 78]}],
valueAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "{0}%"
    }
},
categoryAxis: {
    categories: [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]
},
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "#= category # value: #= value # %"
}
      });
```

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/2dNcP/88/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one

.k-tooltip 
    {
    margin-left: -100px;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:
http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=3831

idem est:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myDivId_tt_active {
       background-color: #FFFFFF;
       left: 14px;
    }
</style>
<div id="myDivId"/>
```

grab your element ID and concatenate with tt (from tooltip I guess) and active to style it. Simple as that.